# Centering an image on a html page

Tags: html

I have a html page and I want to overlay an image in the middle of a page, like putting a stamp mark on a sheet of paper.  The image has transparent background.  I know I can use absolute positioning, but is there a way to center it using css?

Comment: Absolute positioning is CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: Absolute positioning is only thing I know; but I am concern with screen   re-sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<img src="image.png" class="center" />
```

css:

```
.center
{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    width:220px; // image width
    height:40px; // image height
    margin-top: -20px; // -(height/2)
    margin-left: -110px; // -(width/2)
}
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/Bm5tA/

Comment: This works almost good.  Horizontal centering is a little bit off.

Answer (score 0):

To center an image, you can just do this:

```
#watermark{
    display:block;
    margin:auto; //That will center it on all side
}
```

If you only want to center it horizontally:

```
#watermark{
   display:block;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough.  I will give it a try.

Comment: That did not overlay the image on the page.  It centers but also pushes other element down.

Comment: Put it at the bottom of the file

Comment: Then it only appears centering at the bottom of page, but not overlaying the page

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="watermark">
<p>This is the test version.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#watermark {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  font-size: 200pt;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left:-100px;
  top:-200px;
}
```

**Fiddle** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HXUKZ/)